# Sessions in Scala.JS (and Play)

Tags: playframework, session-cookies, scala.js

I want to get a very simple user authentification going in a web-app that is written in Scala.JS and whose backend is implemented in Play 2.6.

Using the Scala.JS [RosHTTP-library](https://github.com/hmil/RosHTTP), my user-client creates requests to the server of the form:

```
HttpRequest("http://localhost:9000/lookup")
  .withQueryParameters(("tag1", input1), ("tag2", input2))
  .send()
  .onComplete({
    case response: Success[SimpleHttpResponse] => {
    ...
   })
```

to which the server then responds like this:

```
Ok(resultSet.asJson.toString())
   .withCookies(Cookie("connected", "blue", httpOnly = false))
```

However, it seems the client will not add the received cookie to subsequent requests, when using the above code. The RosHTTP documentation also mentions the possibility to manually set/send the cookie, but this will add to a browser-failure due to forbidden header (and rightly so, according to the specifications!):

```
request.withHeaders("Cookie" -> "connected=blue")
```

Interestingly, when I use `org.scalajs.dom.XMLHttpRequest` directly without a fancy wrapper like RosHTTP, then I can do the following:

```
val request = new XMLHttpRequest()
request.open("GET", "http://localhost:9000/lookup?tag1=input1")
request.withCredentials = true
request.onload = { ... }
request.send()
```

which effectively makes the browser attach the previously received cookie to this request (note the `withCredentials`-bit here!) as I wanted it to be the case.

But this is unsatisfactory and therefore my question is: is there really no way to achieve the same in RosHTTP? Do I really have to use the `XMLHttpRequest`-stuff directly without any fancy wrapper? Or what would be the idomatic way of achieving a very bare-bones session management system using Scala.JS (and Play)? (By the way, on the Play-side, I also tried `withSession` instead of `withCookie` but to no avail.)

Comment: That's actually pretty weird, and may be a RosHTTP-specific issue.  Scala.js has no effect whatsoever on cookie or session management -- it's just a language, and follows precisely the same rules as JavaScript in the browser.  Normally, a cookie will adhere to the site until it is removed or times out; I don't know why RosHTTP is causing weird effects there.  (Indeed, I don't know *how* it could be causing weird effects, unless it is manipulating the cookies directly, client-side...)

Comment: Thanks for your insightful comment. Obviously, I'm not very familiar with the various web standards down to the specification level, but it seems to me that the problem is RosHTTP's lack of an equivalent to `withCredentials`. A superficial grep of the RosHTTP source code shows no handling of sessions, cookies or credentials whatsoever -- which leaves me with two options: a) try and patch RosHTTP or b) use `XMLHttpRequest` natively.

Comment: Well, keep in mind that there are *many* AJAX libraries out there, including the capabilities built into jQuery (probably the most-used of all browser libraries).  RosHTTP is far from the only wrapper.  Not to mention that Play can generate the client-side call code with JavaScriptReverseRoute -- see [here](https://github.com/jducoeur/Querki/blob/master/querki/scalajvm/app/views/client.scala.html#L82-L112) for an example...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Mystery solved: the problem was that I was basically making a **cross-site request** using cookies, which for security reasons absolutely requires the setting of the aforementioned Boolean property, `withCredentials`, in the underlying transportation layer. The possibility to set it has now been added to the RosHTTP library.

It is important to note that for same-site requests, this flag is/was not required nor does setting or unsetting it make a difference.